# nginx proxy on domain only

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have setup a server block with a proxy in nginx which works when I hit the service with an a directory.

For example I can access gs.geolytix.net/geoserver with this conf.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name gs.geolytix.net;
  location /geoserver {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://138.68.137.90:8080/geoserver;
  }
}
```

So far so good. What I would like to achieve though is that I get to the same address but only address gs.geolytix.net in the browser. Without a directory. If I change the location to / alone I go to gs.geolytix.net the response is gs.geolytix.net//

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the root URI `/` to quietly map to `/geoserver`, then a simple method is with an internal rewrite:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /geoserver last;
}
```

EDIT: If you want an external rewrite, use the same location block with a return statement:

```
location = / {
    return 302 /geoserver;
}
```

The location directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). The rewrite and return directives are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What I looking for is a simple re-write. When I enter gs.geolytix.net I want to get gs.geolytix.net/geoserver in the browser. Currently I get the default nginx page when I type the domain without a directory address.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in combination with the proxy_pass. If I add the return inside the location location block I am no longer able to restart the nginx service.

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be the long form if the short URI is used. Either 301 or 302 will work as a response code.

Comment: that works. perfect...

Comment: it's actually a live example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having a "URI" in the proxy_pass, which acts a sort of implicit rewrite:

```
location / {
    # Note the "/" at the end of the proxy_pass, this will cause it to 
    # replace the location block (/ in this case) with "/geoserver/"
    # when talking to origin.
    # So gs.geolytix.net/test becomes 138.68.137.90:8080/geoserver/test
    proxy_pass http://138.68.137.90:8080/geoserver/;
}
```